# Expression of an integral in terms of lengths of disjoint intervals of a certain set

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function such that $$f:(0,1)\to[0,\infty).$$
Let
$$S_f(y)=\text{the sum of the length of the disjoint intervals whose union}$$
$$\text{is the set} \{x\in (0,1): f(x)>y\}, \ y>0.$$
Let $1\leq p<\infty.$ Show that
$$\int_0^1(f(x))^p\, dx=p\int_0^{\infty}y^{p-1}S_f(y)\, dy.$$

I begin with taking $f(x)=0$ and the result holds trivially. Then I take $f(x)=x$ but with the example I am not able to compute $S_f(y)$.

Basically, I have not understood how $S_f(y)$ will be computed. Further, how this helps in showing the integral.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A standard applicatio of Fubini's Theorem says $\int_0^1(f(x))^p\, dx=p\int_0^{\infty}y^{p-1}|\{x:f(x)>y\}| dy$ and $s_f(y)=|\{x:f(x)>y\}|$ [$|E|$ denotes Lebesgue measure of $E$].